Prove that if $ \varphi : [c, d] \to [a, b] $ is a decreasing diffeomorphism, then $ \int_{[c, d]} \varphi^* \omega = \int_{[a, b]} \omega. $

Prove that if $\varphi : [c, d] \to [a, b] $ is a decreasing
diffeomorphism, then $$ \int_{[c, d]} \varphi^* \omega = \int_{[a, b]}
 \omega. $$

My take on it by the simplest case is given below, but does it hold?
The pullback of $\omega$, $\phi$, is defined by $\phi^*$:
\begin{equation}
    \varphi^* \omega(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k) = \omega(\varphi_* v_1, \varphi_* v_2, \dots, \varphi_* v_k),
\end{equation}
Let us consider the simplest case of a 1-form for $ \omega $. For a tangent vector $ v $ at $ p \in M $, the pullback of $ \omega $ by $ \varphi $ is:
\begin{equation}
    \varphi^* \omega(v) = \omega(\varphi_* v).
\end{equation} Then, for a simple $1$-form,  the pullback must apply also to the unit vector itself, with the unit vector, $\hat{v}$ and give the unit vector itself, such that:
\begin{equation}
    \varphi^* \omega(\hat{v}) = \omega(\varphi_* \hat{v})=\omega,
\end{equation}
So we can write:
$$
\int_{[c, d]} \varphi^* \omega = \int_{[a, b]} \omega=\int_a^b f(t)dt.
$$
I think I may have been too simple here, but is there any truth in this proposed short proof?
Thanks

This makes sense only when $\omega$ is a $1$-form.  Now write it down explicitly with $\omega = f(t),dt$. Most of what you've written is just meaningless and/or wrong.
